# Python crawl ajax page uses pywebkit and threadpool?

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

I want to use python scrape AJAX sites, I refered to this post:
http://blog.motane.lu/2009/06/18/pywebkitgtk-execute-javascript-from-python/
it uses gtk and pywebkitgtk.

But I want to know how to crawl pages simultaneously(multi-thread).

I write code below , it seems the function do_crawl can not be invoked by pool.apply_async. if use pool.apply, do_crawl will be invoked.

```
import gtk
import webkit
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

class WebView(webkit.WebView):
    def get_html(self):
        self.execute_script('oldtitle=document.title;document.title=document.documentElement.innerHTML;')
        html = self.get_main_frame().get_title()
        self.execute_script('document.title=oldtitle;')
        return html

class Crawler(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, url):
        gtk.gdk.threads_init() # suggested by Nicholas Herriot for Ubuntu Koala
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self._url = url

    def crawl(self):
        view = WebView()
        view.open(self._url)
        view.connect('load-finished', self._finished_loading)
        self.add(view)
        gtk.main()

    def _finished_loading(self, view, frame):
        view.get_html()
        gtk.main_quit()

def main():
    pool = ThreadPool(10)
    [pool.apply_async(do_crawl, ('http://google.com/')) for i in range(100)]
    pool.join()


def do_crawl(url):
    crawler = Crawler(url)
    crawler.crawl()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(
    )
```

Comment: My car doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq for how to formulate your questions better.  @spender, your comment is funny, but discouraging to new people.

Comment: Give us details... why isn't it working? How do you expect it to work? What have you tried?

Comment: Did you solve this? It could be that you have the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708039/urllib2-opener-hangs-if-run-inside-a-thread/12773155#12773155

Comment: not yet, I'll investigate  how to combine threading with Pygtk. Thanks a lot.