# urllib2 opener hangs if run inside a thread

Tags: python, pygtk, urllib2

I have a code that is running fine (connect to a page , get PHPSESSID) .
when i put that code in a function , then made a thread of it :

```
Gdk.threads_enter()
threading.Thread(target=self.do_login,args=()).start()
Gdk.threads_leave()
```

the code hangs on

`f = opener.open(req)`

any ideas why ?

when i force close the application , it completes everything and prints everything in the terminal without errors . why does it hang on that particular line in thread only . it does not outside of a thread .

Comment: how do you know that it hangs on `opener.open(req)`?

Comment: print "got here" ... and re-run the code . but when i hit the close button , everything completes . i found out that if i do a thread.run() instead on thread.start() everything works fine . but the .run() function still keeps my GUI frozen while the requests are processing

Comment: so you see `print "before open()"; sys.stdout.flush()`, but not `print "after"`. Is it correct? What are you trying to achieve with threads_enter/leave here? If `self.do_login()` touches GUI directly then you should move threads_enter/leave there. How do you initialize threads on startup, how gtk_main is called? Could you provide a minimal complete example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: It's hard to see what your problem is without the minimal code but it seems to me (had a similar problem myself with threads hanging without reason, not related to urllib2) that adding `gobject.threads_init()` before gtk-main is initiated can solve many threading issues for python gtk apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just repost the comment here so that the question can get solved.

As has been mentioned on other posts regarding `pygtk` and `threading`, several hang-behaviours that seem strange appears to be related to not having implemented the following line:

```
gobject.threads_init()
```

Before calling the gtk main-loop. Note though that it has been reported on other questions here on stackoverflow that this solution may or may not work for Windows.